# SUM aggregate function and Subquery -SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, aggregate-functions

I'm using MS SQL Server and I have 2 tables.

Supply_list

```
sl_id(pk) supply_id(fk)*       transaction_id    Qty 
1             14               872670099         3 
2             15               872670100         5 
3             16               872670101         1 
4             16               872670105         4 <
```

- supply_id is a foreign key to the supply_id in amenity table

Supply

```
supply_id(pk)    no_of_units 
----------------------------
13               2 
14               3
15               6
16               10
```

The output should be supply_id then the no. of units available which is equal to No_of_units subtracted by the Qty.

output

```
id      units available 
-------------------------
13           2 
14           0 --> [1]
15           1
16           5 --> [2]
```

[1] Since based on the supply_list table supply_id 14 has 3 for its Qty

[2] There are two records that contains supply_id 16 so we have to add their qty which are 4 and 1 so we have 5. And that 5 would be subtracted from the no_of_units of supply_id 16 and we will get 5 for units available.

Comment: @OMG Ponies-- thanks for the edit :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You left outer JOIN the list table to the parent table
- Subtract the SUM of the list Qty values from the parent no_of_units value
- Use ISNULL in case there are no list rows

Something like

```
SELECT
   S.supply_id,
   S.no_of_units - ISNULL(SUM(SL.Qty), 0) AS [units available]
FROM
   supply S
   LEFT JOIN
   supply_list SL ON S.supply_id = SL.supply_id
GROUP BY
   S.supply_id, S.no_of_units
```

This makes the aggregate more obvious but is the same query

```
SELECT
   S.supply_id,
   S.no_of_units - ISNULL(SL.SumListQty, 0) AS [units available]
FROM
   supply S
   LEFT JOIN
   (
   SELECT supply_id, SUM(Qty) AS SumListQty
   FROM supply_list
   GROUP BY supply_id
   ) SL ON S.supply_id = SL.supply_id
```

Comment: @mmm: you asked a straightforward question with clear logic and sample data (check how it was edited for formatting though). It was clear what you wanted. Keep it up please! (Some questions from other folk are just terrible BTW)

Comment: @gbn- Oops..Sorry, I really don't know how to present my data in an understandable format, so I want to thank the person who edited it for me :))). I still have a lot of things to know about MS SQL, so I'll probably ask questions, soon. Thanks again! :D